# SimpleXMLElement() having issue with webserver

Tags: php, rss

Am trying to read an rss feed into my php application and it works very well on xampp (localhost) but when i upload it online to a webserver it just does not show anything. Please any help will be appreciated. Below is the code am using and i got it from google search.

```
$newsoutput = new SimpleXMLElement('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml', LIBXML_NOCDATA, true);
$newsoutput = json_decode(json_encode($newsoutput), TRUE);
var_dump($newsoutput);
foreach ($newsoutput['channel']['item'] as $item) {
  // iteration occurs here.
}
```

Comment: Is there any error in your server logs ? Take a look at it : [libxml requirements](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.requirements.php)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was from my webserver settings. Below is how i overcame it

```
 function curl_load($url){
                        curl_setopt($ch=curl_init(), CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                        $response = curl_exec($ch);
                        curl_close($ch);
                        return $response;
                    }

                    $url = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/england/rss.xml";
                    $data = curl_load($url);
                    $newsoutput = simplexml_load_string($data, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
                    $newsoutput = json_decode(json_encode($newsoutput), TRUE);
                    var_dump($newsoutput);
```